# django object is getting saved in database, getting showed in django admin, but its not getting rendered in django template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I am facing problem. I am trying to save django model object.
Object is getting saved in database, getting showed in django admin, but its not getting rendered in django template.

Comment: What do you mean, it is not showing? Where is it not showing? And where is the code that is supposed to be showing it?

Comment: I am rendering list of TicketType to template and depending on the date i am showing tickettypes for particular date. So date comparison is not properly getting done. But when i save same object in django admin its getting displayed.

Comment: You need to *show that code*.

Comment: You've just dumped a load of HTML without context. *Which bit* is the problem; and **where is the Django code that populates that template**? I don't understand why you don't give us the relevant code.

Comment: Thank you Daniel for your help. I am using django wagtail, and i am getting all data from self.event from self.events i am getting shows and from shows i am getting tickettypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug this problem, try using [`string_if_invalid`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#how-invalid-variables-are-handled).  (For example: If `show.event` is `None`, `__str__` might crash and won't return any value.)

And also: Instead of `TicketType.objects.create(..)` try `o = TicketType(...)` followed by `o.full_clean()` to detect more problems related to your model.